# nginx get value of proxy_http_header

Tags: nginx

I add an `traceId` in my nginx config via $proxy_http_header.  Here is the config:

```
 location ~ /(xxx.*) {
       
        proxy_set_header trace_id $connection-$connection_requests-$msec;
       
    }
```

Now I need to print it in my Nginx log. How can I get it? It does not work if I get it via $http_trace_id. like

```
log_format normal '$remote_addr' 
                       '"$http_trace_id"';
```

Comment: With `http_<header>` variables you can access only those headers that are coming with the client request. Use an additional variable: `set $trace_id $connection-$connection_requests-$msec; proxy_set_header trace_id $trace_id;` and then use `$trace_id` variable within the log format.

Comment: does this diff between different request scopes? That can't be share between diff request

Comment: Yes, of course. It is much more complex to do the opposite, to share some variable between different requests.